# Vlookup across two worksheets using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

[Source sheet ("Sheet2")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o64a4.png)
[Output sheet ("Sheet3")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkCtW.png)

I have a list of names and associated values in "Sheet2".  I have another list of names in "Sheet3".  Where the name in sheet2 can also be found in Sheet3, i would like to add in the associated value in the column adjacent to the name in Sheet3.

To do this, I've created a nested loop which behaves as follows;

- Loops over all names ("X") in "sheet2"
- For each of these names iterate over all names ("Y") in "sheet 3"
- where the values match, perform a `VLookup` on "Sheet2" and highlight the cell to flag that a value was added.

This code worked fine when the two tables were hosted in the same worksheet.  On attempting to replicate this behaviour across two different worksheets (by ensuring that explicit worksheet references were added to all ranges) it doesnt do anything.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
Sub colincrosssheet()

On Error Resume Next

Dim inputrange As Range
Dim outputrange As Range
Dim X As Range
Dim Y As Range
Dim inputtoprow As Integer
Dim inputbottomrow As Integer
Dim inputcolumn As Integer
Dim outputtoprow As Integer
Dim outputbottomrow As Integer
Dim outputcolumn As Integer
Dim rngFindin As Range
Dim rngFindout As Range
Dim vlookuprange As Range

'set input column, which contains the line item ids from Pacing Tool, and also sets bottom row
Set rngFindin = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find("nameinput", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If rngFindin Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Could not find 'Line Item Id' column in your SDF. Please review file.", vbOKOnly, "Column not found"
Else
    inputtoprow = Worksheets("Sheet2").rngFindin.Row + 1
    inputcolumn = Worksheets("Sheet2").rngFindin.Column
    inputbottomrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, inputcolumn).End(xlUp).Row
End If

'set output column, which contains the line item ids in the SDF, and also sets bottom row
Set rngFindout = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells.Find("nameoutput", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If rngFindout Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Could not find 'Line Item Id' column in your SDF. Please review file.", vbOKOnly, "Column not found"
Else
    outputtoprow = Worksheets("Sheet3").rngFindout.Row + 1
    outputcolumn = Worksheets("Sheet3").rngFindout.Column
    outputbottomrow = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, outputcolumn).End(xlUp).Row
End If

'define Vlookup range'
Set vlookuprange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(inputtoprow, inputcolumn), Cells(inputbottomrow, inputcolumn + 1))

'defines input and output range which contain line item ids
Set inputrange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(inputtoprow, inputcolumn), Cells(inputbottomrow, inputcolumn))
Set outputrange = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(outputtoprow, outputcolumn), Cells(outputbottomrow, outputcolumn))

'loop through input range and update relevant column in SDF with new bid values
For Each X In Worksheets("Sheet2").inputrange
    For Each Y In Worksheets("Sheet3").outputrange
        If Worksheets("Sheet3").Y.Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").X.Value Then
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Y.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("Sheet2").X.Value, Worksheets("Sheet2").vlookuprange, 2, False)
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Y.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
        End If
    Next Y
Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `inputbottomrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, inputcolumn).End(xlUp).Row` is not fully qualified, modify to `inputbottomrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, inputcolumn).End(xlUp).Row` , same goes for `outputbottomrow = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, outputcolumn).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: You need to correct everywhere you have `Worksheets("foo").Range(Cells...)` to `Worksheets("foo").Range(Worksheets("foo").Cells(...)`. You are better off defiining the worksheets like `Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` Then it is easier to quickly refer to `ws1` instead of typing out `Worksheets("Sheet1")` all the time..

Comment: why not use a formula to do this? Use a combination of Index & Match to do this.

Comment: Hi Shai/Robin, thanks for both your speedy input.  It looks as though there are two slightly different syntaxes in your replies.  I've amended the first line of code to match both of your suggestions.

Comment: Set rngFindin = sh2.Range(sh2.Cells.Find("nameinput", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole))

Comment: Set rngFindin = sh2.Cells(sh2.Find("nameinput", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole))

Comment: however both of these are returning the error message suggesting they cannot find the "nameinput" text in the worksheet sh2 (where sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer (code and explanation) are a little long, but I wanted to share some of the reasons your code didn't work, and what I've done in my updated version below:

**First**, organzied data related to your InputSheet ("Sheet2") in one section, under `With Worksheets("Sheet2")`. The same for your OutputSheet ("Sheet3"), under `With Worksheets("Sheet3")`.

**Second**, I've replaced your double `For` loop and `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` with one `For` and a `Application.Match` - that will save you a lot of run time.

Some of the errors you have:

- Since you aready Set `outputrange` before, when you run this line `For Each Y in Worksheets("Sheet3").outputrange` will raise an error, instead you can use `For Each Y In OutputRange`
- Some of your "lastrow" and "lastcolumn" value are not fully qualified, `inputbottomrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, inputcolumn).End(xlUp).Row` needs to be `inputbottomrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, inputcolumn).End(xlUp).Row`. That's why I either defined a variable of type `Worksheet` and assign it to it, or use a `With` statement.

*Side-Note*: I've modified the variables with CAPITAL letters in the begining (it's my way to debug I don't have any **Typos** when coding)

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub colincrosssheet()

On Error Resume Next

Dim InputtopRow As Long
Dim InputbottomRow As Long
Dim Inputcolumn As Long
Dim OutputtopRow As Long
Dim OutputbottomRow As Long
Dim OutputColumn As Long

Dim rngFindin As Range
Dim rngFindout As Range
Dim VlookupRange As Range
Dim InputRange As Range
Dim OutputRange As Range
Dim X As Range
Dim Y As Range

' set input column, which contains the line item ids from Pacing Tool, and also sets bottom row
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngFindin = .Cells.Find("nameinput", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If rngFindin Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find 'Line Item Id' column in your SDF. Please review file.", vbOKOnly, "Column not found"
    Else
        InputtopRow = rngFindin.Row + 1
        Inputcolumn = rngFindin.Column
        InputbottomRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Inputcolumn).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    ' define input range which contain line item ids
    Set InputRange = .Range(.Cells(InputtopRow, Inputcolumn), .Cells(InputbottomRow, Inputcolumn))
End With

'set output column, which contains the line item ids in the SDF, and also sets bottom row
With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set rngFindout = .Cells.Find("nameoutput", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If rngFindout Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find 'Line Item Id' column in your SDF. Please review file.", vbOKOnly, "Column not found"
    Else
        OutputtopRow = rngFindout.Row + 1
        OutputColumn = rngFindout.Column
        OutputbottomRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, OutputColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    ' define output range which contain line item ids
    Set OutputRange = .Range(.Cells(OutputtopRow, OutputColumn), .Cells(OutputbottomRow, OutputColumn))
End With

Dim MatchRow As Variant
' loop through outputrange and update relevant column in SDF with new bid values
For Each Y In OutputRange
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Y.value, InputRange, 0)) Then ' check if Y is found anywhere in inputrange using the Match
        MatchRow = Application.Match(Y.value, InputRange, 0) + rngFindin.Row

        Y.Offset(, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(MatchRow, Inputcolumn + 1)
        Y.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
    End If
Next Y

End Sub
```

Comment: @Colin Blyth have you tested my code above ? any feedback ?

Comment: Hello Shai, the code works perfectly, really appreciate your comments and very comprehensive explanation. Thanks again for your help